# Adding a User Control that contains an Ajax Toolkit object

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I created a User Control:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">  
</ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

   <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
      Start Date   
    </td>   
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="StartDateTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="StartCal" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="dateSelectionChanged"
                runat="server" TargetControlID="StartDateTextBox">
      </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
      <asp:Button ID="PostBackButton" runat="server" Text="Button" Style="display: none"
                OnClick="PostBackButton_Click" />
    </td>
    <td>
       End Date
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="EndDateTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

      <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="EndCal" runat="server" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="dateSelectionChanged"
                TargetControlID="EndDateTextBox">
      </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <asp:Chart ID="PlantRestarts" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="800px">
      <Series>
          <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Bar" Palette="BrightPastel" ChartArea="MainChartArea">
          </asp:Series>
      </Series>
      <ChartAreas>
          <asp:ChartArea Name="MainChartArea" Area3DStyle-Enable3D="true">
          </asp:ChartArea>
      </ChartAreas>
      </asp:Chart>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="4">
      <asp:Button ID="PlantRestartsButton" runat="server" Text="Export To CSV" CommandName="Export"
                CommandArgument="PlantRestarts" OnClick="PlantRestartAttemptsButton_Click" />
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have a simple page that uses this control:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CustomTestPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="TrendReporting.CustomTestPage" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="UserCtrl" TagName="CustomControl"  Src="Controls/TestUserControl.ascx" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getSlide() {
        var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
            x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
            y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
            x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            if (x == "slide") {
                return y;
            }
        }
    }

    var isPostBack = false;
    var current = getSlide();
    var slider2 = ['Books', 'Attempts', 'Attempt Book Comparison', 'Business Unit', 'Trend'];
    function formatText(index, panel) {
        return slider2[index - 1];
    }

    $(function () {

        if (!isPostBack) {
            slide = 1;
        }

        $('#slider2').anythingSlider({

            width: 800,       // if resizeContent is false, this is the default width  if panel size is not defined
            height: 400,       // if resizeContent is false, this is the default height if panel size is not defined
            buildArrows: true,
            startPanel: current,
            resizeContents: false,     // If true, solitary images/objects in the panel will expand to fit the viewport
            delay: 7000,    //7 seconds before transitioning to next slide
            autoPlay: true,     // This turns off the entire slideshow FUNCTIONALY, not just if it starts running or not
            navigationFormatter: formatText, // Format navigation labels with text
            forwardText: "&raquo;",
            backText: "&laquo;",
            onSlideComplete: function () {
                document.cookie = "slide=" +    $('#slider2').data('AnythingSlider').currentPage;
            }
        })
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<ul id="slider2">
 <li class="panel1" style="width: 800px; height: 400px">
    <UserCtrl:CustomControl runat="server" />
</li>
</ul>
```

When I load the page, nothing shows up at all, just a blank page. The problem is that it injects a script tag into the < li> tags from the ajax toolscriptmanager. The source code shows this:

```
    <ul id="slider2">
 <li class="panel1" style="width: 800px; height: 400px">
    <script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$ToolkitScriptManager1', 'ctl01', [], [], [], 90, 'ctl00');
 //]]>
 </script>

<table>
   <tr>
        <td>
            Start Date
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$StartDateTextBox" type="text" id="MainContent_ctl00_StartDateTextBox" />

            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$PostBackButton" value="Button" id="MainContent_ctl00_PostBackButton" style="display: none" />
        </td>
        <td>
            End Date
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$EndDateTextBox" type="text" id="MainContent_ctl00_EndDateTextBox" />


        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img id="MainContent_ctl00_PlantRestarts" src="/ChartImg.axd?i=chart_bbf484b6c44a4372abba2bb2591a3fb6_5.png&amp;g=dbfe90c2079e4257937543c8dc544c65" alt="" style="height:400px;width:800px;border-width:0px;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4">
            <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$PlantRestartsButton" value="Export To CSV" id="MainContent_ctl00_PlantRestartsButton" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>





</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to fix this at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use the `ToolkitScriptManager`, but I do often use the general `ScriptManager` for ajax functionality on my sites.  With the `ScriptManager`, I usually place it in the MasterPage as there can only be one instance on any particular page and by placing it just within the form tag it doesn't interfere with any HTML rendering.